# .htaccess URL rewrite with random parameters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-routing

I'm currently writing a PHP app and am about to create various controllers. Currently I have one controller with certain method, so the URL looks like this:

```
http://somewebsite.com/index.php?c=controller&a=action
```

It's being rewritten to this:

```
http://somewebsite.com/controller/action
```

With this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ index.php?c=$1&a=$2 [NC]
```

What I want to achieve is the ability to rewrite URL with more than one controller (the more, the better), possibly in random order. Is there a more convenient way than rewriting every possible combination of URL parameters?

Comment: I think you should show some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many frameworks (Codeigniter, WordPress, Laravel, etc.) use an `.htaccess` file similar to the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This rewrites all incoming URLs to be handled by the `index.php` file. You can then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable to get the exact request URI, parse it, and then handle it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you're going for an arbitrary routing scheme, probably your best bet is to just pass the entire url string  e.g. ^(.+)$ to index.php and let your php application split the string based on '/' and handle the array however makes sense for your application